# How protect chrome extension of reupload

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Everybody can download chrome extension, edit and reupload, how i can protect my chrome extension and what i need to do if i see someone reupload my chrome extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bulletproof-protect it. The only thing you can reasonably guarantee to be unique is the extension ID for published items - but any checks you would do against it can be circumvented.

It's not a technical problem. It's a social/legal problem.

If you see someone doing it, you should use the Report Abuse function of the Web Store.

Answer (score 0):

What other does is to load the "actual" code of their extension remotely (via CDN)

The code that is packaged with chrome extension just act as loader or their "real" extension code.

See Streak's InboxSDK (sdk to build chrome extensions for gmail). It uses the same concept. https://www.inboxsdk.com/docs/

Comment: Which is something Google seriously frowns upon and Mozilla outright bans.

Comment: Besides, how do you make sure it's your extension requesting the extra code? There is no field in the request that can't be forged that shows the origin. There are no secret keys that can't be extracted.